Why Azure DevOps - compare Source vs Forked branch, always shows differences based on the date when the fork was created?
We have a "Repo1" in a Azure DevOps "Proj1", We have forked that Repo1 to new Project "Proj2". Now there are changes in "Proj1\Repo1\File1", we create a pull request from "Proj1\Repo1" to "Proj2\Repo1", now Azure devops displays list of files changed as 1. Which is fine. After successfully completing the pull request, we can see the updates in "Proj2". Now if I create a same Pull request, Azure devops still shows 1 file change exist. Is this a defect in Azure devops? Is there a way to see ACTUAL CURRENT differences between Forked repo vs Original Repo from which it was forked, in the UI or by any command.


What is the type of your Azure DevOps, Azure DevOps Services (cloud) or Azure DevOps Server (on-premises)? If Azure DevOps Server, what is the version of it?

You can get the detailed version information of Azure DevOps Server from the link: https://{server-name}/{collection-name}/_home/About. Replace the {server-name} and {collection-name} with the actual names of your server and collection.

@BrightRan-MSFT        About Azure DevOps Server
Version Azure DevOps Server 2022.1 (AzureDevOpsServer_20240130.2)

Try to update your Azure DevOps Server 2022 to the latest version. @user1066231

I attempted on my Azure DevOps Server 2022 and did not reproduce the same issue, everything can work as expected.
Your Azure DevOps Server 2022 is not the latest version. See the Release notes of Azure DevOps Server 2022.
You can try to update it to the latest version, then check whether the issue can be fixed.

EDIT:




So, in your DevOps when you create a new Pull request in forked project, it displays 0 Files changed? - Hope you verified the Source and Destination correctly..

@user1066231, Yes, after I successfully merging changes from "Proj1\Repo1" to "Proj2\Repo1.Fork" using a PR, if I try to create a same new PR, it always says no changes which is the expected behavior. See EDIT.

@user1066231, Have you tried to upgrade your Azure DevOps Server 2022 to the latest version? Does the issue get fixed?

I have requested my organization. Hope it will take a while

@user1066231, Go ahead.
